# Trimming and extracting value from json structured data - Redshift DBT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbt

Got a String type column that has data like below:

```
mycol
  [{'Title': 'First Name'}]
  [{'Title': 'Test User'}]
  [{'Title': 'some name'}, {'Title': 'second name'}]
```

How to extract the values from these columns?
Expected output:

```
extracted_mycol
 First Name
 Test User
 Some name, second name
```

The column is a string type and not JSON type.

I tried:

1 -- `TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(mycol, '{"Title":"', ''), '"}', ''))`

2 -- `JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(REPLACE(Id, '''', '"'),'Title')`

None of these methods are working. I just want to simply extract the values from the columns. any help pls?

Answer (score 1):

you have several issues going on. you recognize that the json isn’t valid unless it uses double quotes, good. however i don’t think that you can escape a single quote with another single quote. you need backslash - ‘\’’.  check your replace() function output to ensure you get the right double quoting.

next issue is that your json is an array at the top level so you need to use JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT() first. however this just gets a single element of the array. this will work for your first 2 examples but not the last.

so you will likely want to convert your json to a super data type as this will enable some higher power actions like unnesting the array. the JSON_PARSE() function will do this. next you can unroll the array as described here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html.  then you can list_agg() the the values back into a single row/varchar. this way it doesn’t matter how many elements are in the array.

Comment: thanks! I have an extraction running befo rethe data comes into the system. Originally my extraction was pulling data in super type and I used serialize function to process the JSON. tricky thing is when data comes in JSON structure but string datatype